# Generate synthetic data for majority and minority classes

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, imbalanced-data, oversampling

I am working on a classification problem where I try to generate synthetic data for both the Majority and Minority classes,as i want to train my model on synthetic data and test on actual data, i am using below code, but i am unable to generate the synthetic data for majority class, how can I do it?

Code:

```
# columns for each type
continuous_cols = ['amt', 'BAL', 'MOB', 'TPOP']
boolean_cols = ['EVER_L3M','EVER_L3M', 'EVER_L6M']
target_col = 'Target'  

import pandas as pd
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTENC, RandomOverSampler

def oversample_both_classes(df, continuous_cols, boolean_cols, target_col):
    # Separate features and target
    X = df.drop(target_col, axis=1)
    y = df[target_col]

    # Calculate boolean and continuous indices
    boolean_indices = [X.columns.get_loc(col) for col in boolean_cols]
    continuous_indices = [X.columns.get_loc(col) for col in continuous_cols]

    
    categorical_indices = boolean_indices + continuous_indices

    # Oversample minority class with SMOTENC
    smotenc = SMOTENC(random_state=42, categorical_features=boolean_indices)
    X_resampled_minority, y_resampled_minority = smotenc.fit_resample(X, y)

    # Oversample majority class with RandomOverSampler
    ros = RandomOverSampler(random_state=42)
    X_resampled_majority, y_resampled_majority = ros.fit_resample(X, y)

    
    X_resampled = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(X_resampled_minority, columns=X.columns),
                            pd.DataFrame(X_resampled_majority, columns=X.columns)])
    y_resampled = pd.concat([pd.Series(y_resampled_minority), pd.Series(y_resampled_majority)])

    
    resampled_df = pd.DataFrame(X_resampled, columns=X.columns)
    resampled_df[target_col] = y_resampled

    return resampled_df


oversampled_df_PL = oversample_both_classes(df, continuous_cols, boolean_cols, target_col)
```

Comment: It is clear from `RandomOverSampler` [docs](http://glemaitre.github.io/imbalanced-learn/generated/imblearn.over_sampling.RandomOverSampler.html) that oversampling is performed on the **minority** class(es); not sure why you expected this to work here.

Comment: Please help to correct it and guide me to achieve the objective.

Comment: The only way I can think of is actually a hack: *flipping* the labels temporarily, applying SMOTE to the "minority" (actually majority) class, and then flipping them again. At least this way you will have actual synthetic samples of the majority class (instead of mere copies of existing ones, which would be the case if your approach here actually worked).